# LINQ version of looping through array and performing multiple types of replacements

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of strings defined called currentRow. I have a loop that looks something like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < currentRow.Length; index++)
{
    if (currentRow[index] == string.Empty)
    {
        currentRow[index] = null;
    }

    if (currentRow[index] == "''")
    {
        currentRow[index] = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

If I were to do this as a LINQ query instead, what would it look like? Am I better off using a loop instead for this? It seems like with a LINQ query I would have to create multiple copies of the array.

Comment: Linq is for _querying_, not _updating.  You can project to a _new_ array but there's not a Linq mechanism to update a collection without bastardizing a lambda function with side-effects. Stick to the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I were to do this as a LINQ query instead, what would it look like?

If you want to project to a *new* array (and optionally overwrite the existing reference) it would look like:

```
currentRow.Select(r => r == string.Empty ? null : 
                       r == "''" ? string.Empty : r)
          .ToArray();
```

If you wanted to use Linq to *modify* the original collection it would look like a evil lambda with side-effects too horrible to utter in this place.

> Am I better off using a loop instead for this?

Probably. You avoid the creation of a new array.

> It seems like with a LINQ query I would have to create multiple copies of the array.

No, just one additional copy.  And if you overwrite the original reference (and if nothing else has a reference to it) it would get garbage collected as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**You need projection, not selection.**

It's important to remember that LINQ is designed for querying and not actually updating existing values.

If you wanted to do what you are indicating, you could use LINQ to create a projection of your existing collection that would map your values to others via a [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) statement :

```
// This would project each element from your currentRow array and set its value to
// either null (if it was empty), the empty string (if it was just single quotes) or
// use its original value.
var output = currentRow.Select(x => x == "" ? null : x == "''" ? "" : x).ToArray();
```

**Would a loop be a better option?**

There isn't anything wrong with your current approach. It wouldn't require the creation of an entirely separate array to store your new values in (via a projection). I know that it might not look as concise as a LINQ statement, it still works and is quite readable (unlike how some LINQ queries can become).